# Python matplotlib animation: Create solid of revolution toward y-axis for sin(x/2)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a solid of revolution for **sin(x/2)** toward y-axis from x=0 to x=2pi.

I am able to create the solid of revolution toward x-axis:

[image: 1]

this is the code:

```
import gif
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

@gif.frame
def plot_volume(angle):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 15))

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = '3d')
    angles = np.linspace(0, 360, 20)
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
    v = np.linspace(0, 2*angle, 60)

    U, V = np.meshgrid(x, v)
    Y1 = np.sin(U/2)*np.cos(V)
    Z1 = np.sin(U/2)*np.sin(V)
    X = U
    ax2.plot_surface(X, Y1, Z1, alpha = 0.2, color = 'blue', rstride = 6, cstride = 6)
    ax2.set_xlim(-3,3)
    ax2.set_ylim(-3,3)
    ax2.set_zlim(-3,3)
    ax2.view_init(elev = 50, azim = 30*angle)
    ax2.plot_wireframe(X, Y1, Z1, color = 'black')
    ax2._axis3don = False

frames = []
for i in np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 20):
    frame = plot_volume(i)
    frames.append(frame)

gif.save(frames, '/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/Python/solidofrevolutionxaxis.gif', duration = 500)
```

The question and the problem is:

1. Why the function of numpy `np.arcsin` can't be used as the inverse of sine function to create the solid of revolution for sin(x/2) toward the y axis?

This is the code for trying to rotate sin(x/2) from x=0 to x=2pi toward y-axis. And it fails

```
import gif
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

@gif.frame
def plot_volume(angle):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 15))

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = '3d')
    angles = np.linspace(0, 360, 20)
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 60)
    v = np.linspace(0, 2*angle, 60)

    U, V = np.meshgrid(x, v)
    Y1 = 2*np.arcsin(U)*np.cos(V)
    Z1 = 2*np.arcsin(U)*np.sin(V)
    X = U
    ax2.plot_surface(X, Y1, Z1, alpha = 0.2, color = 'blue', rstride = 6, cstride = 6)
    ax2.set_xlim(-3,3)
    ax2.set_ylim(-3,3)
    ax2.set_zlim(-3,3)
    ax2.view_init(elev = 50, azim = 30*angle)
    ax2.plot_wireframe(X, Y1, Z1, color = 'black')
    ax2._axis3don = False

frames = []
for i in np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 20):
    frame = plot_volume(i)
    frames.append(frame)

gif.save(frames, '/home/browni/LasthrimProjection/Python/solidofrevolutionyaxis.gif', duration = 500)
```

it should look like half circle not like this:
[image: 2]

Comment: Is this a math question or a programming question?

Comment: Both, primarily is python programming to create the solid of revolution toward y axis , because in this case I need enlightenment how to achieve that. You need a bit of math to make the correct python code too.